# spring-mvc and thymeleaf integration on another module

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hello my problem is that i have 2 web applications, both spring MVC with thymeleaf on them, but in both of them the header and footer are the same, is it possible for me to save the header and footer in a separate module without having to create a new webapp just for these 2 fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a really good way to learn about how to use the fragments:

[Thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)